# Running ROS across multiple machines is failed

Tags: rosnode, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am trying to run ROS across 2 machines, master is starting with out any issues when I tried to run listener getting below errors.

```
root@test:/opt/ros/indigo# rosrun rospy_tutorials listener.py
[rospack] Error: package ‘rospy_tutorials’ not found
find: ‘’: No such file or directory
```

I have followed below procedures.

System 1-

setting static IP-

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add default gw 192.168.0.1 dev eth0

export ROS_IP=192.168.0.1
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.0.1

roscore &

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.1:11311/
rosrun rospy_tutorials listener.py
```

System-2

setting static IP-

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add default gw 192.168.0.2 dev eth0

export ROS_IP=192.168.0.2
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.0.2

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.1:11311/
rosrun rospy_tutorials talker.py
```

Note: I could able to ping between system 1 & 2.

Kindly help us to debug this issue in my setup.

Kindly let me know if you need any more information,

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278817/running-ros-across-multiple-machines-is-failed/) by [Bharathraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/33149/bharathraj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-04**:
Welcome! What's the issue here? The error message or a network problem? Being able to ping isn't sufficient. You need to make sure that you can [communicate over all ports](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Further_check:_netcat).

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-04**:
Also, `ROS_HOSTNAME` is for host names, not IP addresses. For an IP address use `ROS_IP`. http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME

**Comment by [Bharathraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/33149/bharathraj/) on 2018-01-05**:
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost $
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

roslaunch rospy_tutorials talker_listener.launch

with the above steps, it works fine ..

As you pointed out Looks like it's a network/setup issue. Since I am new to ROS finding difficult to figure it out

**Comment by [Bharathraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/33149/bharathraj/) on 2018-01-05**:
after adding this to env setup it's resolved now

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/hjt/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

Thanks for ur support,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I doubt this is a problem that is caused by "multiple machines" being involved.

The error is:

> ```
> [rospack] Error: package ‘rospy_tutorials’ not found
> ```

```
find: ‘’: No such file or directory
```

That error seems to indicate that the package `rospy_tutorials` is either not installed on the machine, or is not part of the workspace that is currently `source`d.

Can you make sure that:

1. the `rospy_tutorials` package is installed on the machine called `test`?
2. the `root` user has `source`d the appropriate setup files (note: running as `root` is generally not recommended)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bharathraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/33149/bharathraj/) on 2018-01-05**:
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

roslaunch rospy_tutorials talker_listener.launch

with the above steps, it works fine  & that means rospy_tutorials  is installed on the machines.

I am suspecting it could be related to env setup.

**Comment by [Bharathraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/33149/bharathraj/) on 2018-01-05**:
after adding this to env setup it's resolved now

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/hjt/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

Thanks for ur support,

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-06**:
I would recommend you `source /home/hjt/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` instead of manually setting the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. Setting that variable manually should almost never be necessary.

Also: please consider not running nodes as `root`, it's rarely necessary.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-06**:
According to your comment it was essentially option 2 then in my answer that was the cause.